# SaveChanges() returns 0 but ChangeTracker.HasChanges() returns true

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to update my user record. But "savechanges" method returns 0. Even when "haschanges" method returns true.

```
public async Task UpdateUser(UserModel model)
    {
        var user = GetById(model.UserId);
        user.ProfileImageUrl = model.ProfileImageUrl;
        user.Email = model.Email;
        user.Nickname = model.Nickname;
        _context.Update(user);
        bool a = _context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
        var donus = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

[image]

I can see the changes BTW.

[image]

> my view

[image: my view]

> my controller

[image]

Comment: The line `_context.Update(user)` isn't necessary. But does EF actually save the changes?

Comment: Can you check what changes the changeset has and verify if they are applied to the database?

Comment: Yes, it does. Updated my question.

Comment: They are not applied to my database. I'm trying to do that.

Comment: Please show us how `UpdateUser` is called.

Comment: You forgot to await `UpdateUser`.

Comment: Yeah.. I guess I'm stupid. Thanks, appreciate it!

Comment: It isn't stupid. It is _common_ though, which is why I asked to see how it was called.